# Integrate HTTP request/response with asynchronous messages in RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq, akka-http

Our app is a message processing system with multiple components connected with RabbitMQ queues. So the message processing are asynchronous. Now I need to add a HTTP adapter that communicates with the system. Since HTTP is synchronous with request/response, I need a way to connect synchronous and asynchronous flows. The current solution is:

1. HTTP requests are sent to one queue. Each request has a unique request ID for correlation.
2. HTTP request is blocked by a `CompletableFuture`.
3. The request is processed and response is sent back to another queue.
4. Queue consumer uses response to complete the `CompletableFuture` matching with request ID.

The HTTP adapter is implemented using Akka HTTP. Requests are handled using `handleWithAsyncHandler()` with a function of type `Function<HttpRequest, CompletionStage<HttpResponse>>`.

The problem is that the HTTP adapter needs to manage a map (`Map<String, CompletableFuture>`) of all pending requests. For each request, a new `CompletableFuture` object is created and put into the map. When a response is received in the queue, the matching `CompletableFuture` is completed to finish the request.  This seems a bad smell in the code because I need to carefully manage this map. For example, if a response failed to generate for a request, the request needs to be removed from the map.

I wonder if there are other ways than using a map to track all pending requests.

Comment: While it may be a bit heavyweight for this use-case, Apache Camel would be able to accomplish this exact concept with relative ease. For the most basic use-case, I imagine you could wire this up with just a few lines of code or XML configuration.

Comment: It looks like a `long polling` HTTP server. I think this [discussion](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/20121) is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, akka-http could be async style. You do not need to implement that queue to map the request Id.

One thing needs to be considered that **DO NOT use the default dispatcher**.

Better to define a blocking dispatcher to handle CompletableFuture.supplyAsync

For example

```
my-blocking-dispatcher {
  type = Dispatcher
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  thread-pool-executor {
    fixed-pool-size = 16
  }
  throughput = 1
}

import static akka.http.javadsl.server.Directives.completeWithFuture;
import static akka.http.javadsl.server.Directives.post;

// GOOD (the blocking is now isolated onto a dedicated dispatcher):
final Route routes = post(() -> {
    final MessageDispatcher dispatcher = system.dispatchers().lookup("my-blocking-dispatcher");
    return completeWithFuture(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000L);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                return HttpResponse.create()
                        .withEntity(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            }, dispatcher // uses the good "blocking dispatcher" that we
            // configured, instead of the default dispatcher to isolate the blocking.
    ));
});
```